# Is there a way to force Notepad++ Encoding to Windows-1252?

Tags: notepad++, encoding, text-editing, utf-8, ansi

Is there a way to force Notepad++ Encoding to Windows-1252 for files that it doesn't auto-detect the encoding?

It seems it defaults to UTF-8 and I want it to default to Windows-1252 instead.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`Settings --> Preferences --> New Document`.  In the `Encoding` box, select the dropdown and you will find `Windows-1252`.  Not sure why you want to use such a thing though as it is a legacy encoding.